# Will a Single XSLT file solve this issue..or...?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Below is my XML File -

```
<CVs>
  <CV>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Address></Address>
    <Introduction></Introduction>
    <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, Oracle, VB.NET</CompSkills>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
  <CV>
  <CV>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Address></Address>
    <Introduction></Introduction>
    <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, JSP, HTML</CompSkills>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
  <CV>
</CVs>
```

below is the XSLT file - a short version to get an idea

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
<table align='center' width='800' style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:13pt;">
<tr><td>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Experience">
<table align='center' width='800' style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:13pt;">
<tr><td>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using Java as front-end. To display the output in HTML format I have an XSLT file. This XSLT file is a standard one ie; it displays all the CVs.

Now what I have to do is use a ListBox with Names of all candidates and when clicked on a particular name ONLY his CV should get displayed. I have coded the Java part to display the names of the candidates into the ListBox. Now have some trouble with displaying the CV of the selected candidate in HTML format.

The current XSLT file is displaying all the CVs. So Will I need another XSLT file which use parameter passed from the program and display its details..? If yes then some help on how to do this... ??

Thanks in advance - John

Comment: Good question, +1. You need to pass the selected name as a global parameter to the transformation -- then it is easy to perform the wanted transformation.

Comment: Dimitre- Thanks a lot for the answer. You mean I will have to extract the required matches first into an XML output and then pass this file to XSLT file to get the HTML output..? Thanks a lot again for the answer. :)

Comment: @_John: No, I meant that in your code that invokes the transformation, you have to set up a parameter with the wanted CV name (or *). I don't know what particular Java XSLT processor you are using. I typically use .NET's XslCompiledTransform and here it is described how to set up an external parameter for the transformation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx For Saxon, do have a look at these sample apps in the Saxon documentation: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.2/samples/intro.html

Comment: @_John: As for producing HTML, You hadn't any complete sample of the wanted output. You need just to override the identity transform with additional templates matching elements that are descendents of `CV`. Or, you could write it more neatly as a two-step transformation, where my solution is the first step, and the second step is the HTML formatting.

Comment: @Dimitre- I am not getting the correct output as required..!! I am using the JAXP, default XSLT processor which comes with JDK 1.7. I am saving the output to an XML file in which I am getting only `<CVs/>` !!

Comment: @Dimitre- It was my fault.. I hadn't replaced the correct tags ;) THANKS A LOT... :)

Comment: @Dimitre- Now suppose I want to pass ANY `<CompSkills>` like Oracle then where and what changes I will need in the XSLT file..?

Comment: @Dimitre- I have worked with the code given by you NOT only for the `<Name>` but also for `<Profile>` and others. Now quite confused with its usage with `<CompSkills>` tag, as if I want to search for Oracle, then `contains(x,y)` would work. But how to use it..? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @_John: Sorry, I was sleeping while you were asking your last four comments. Please, ask a new question -- there are very good XSLT specialists on the other side of the pond, too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an idea how this can be done, here is a *complete* solution that extracts all or just the wanted `CV` element (no HTML formatting is done as this isn't relevant to the question):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pName" select="'XYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CV">
  <xsl:if test="$pName = Name or $pName='*'">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document** (corrected to a well-formed one):

```
<CVs>
  <CV>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Address></Address>
    <Introduction></Introduction>
    <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, Oracle, VB.NET</CompSkills>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
  </CV>
  <CV>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Address></Address>
    <Introduction></Introduction>
    <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, JSP, HTML</CompSkills>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
    <Experience>
      <Profile></Profile>
      <Duration></Duration>
      <Info></Info>
    </Experience>
  </CV>
</CVs>
```

**the wanted, correct (just the `CV` with `Name` XYZ is extracted) is produced**:

```
<CVs>
   <CV>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <Address/>
      <Introduction/>
      <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, JSP, HTML</CompSkills>
      <Experience>
         <Profile/>
         <Duration/>
         <Info/>
      </Experience>
      <Experience>
         <Profile/>
         <Duration/>
         <Info/>
      </Experience>
      <Experience>
         <Profile/>
         <Duration/>
         <Info/>
      </Experience>
   </CV>
</CVs>
```

**Explanation**:

The wanted name or "*" must be passed externally as a global parameter (in this case named `pName`) to the transformation. Read your XSLT processor documentation how this must be done, as this is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add an `xsl:param` to your XSLT and give it a default value; 'All' for example. That way by default it will display all `CV`s.

If you need to display a single `CV` based on a `Name`, you can pass that value (from your ListBox) in your `xsl:param` to display only that `CV`.

Here's an example `xsl:param` and the `xsl:template` needed to display the `CV`s:

```
  <xsl:param name="pName" select="'All'"/>

  <xsl:template match="CV">
    <xsl:if test="$pName = 'All' or Name = $pName">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

If you wanted to display only the `XYZ` CV, you would just use the value `XYZ` for the `pName` param when you called the XSLT.

Comment: @DevNull- Thanks for the answer. I will try it and come back again either with thanks or with issues... :)

Comment: @John - You're very welcome, but maybe you would rather wait to accept my answer? I appreciate it though. :-)

Comment: @DevNull- Ok I have cancelled the acceptance.. After success with the code given, I will surely accept it.. Please don't mind.

Comment: @John - That's the best way to do it :-)