# Will a single XSLT file solve this issue - continuation..?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

This question is connected with this post of mine - [Will a Single XSLT file solve this issue..or...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937310/will-a-single-xslt-file-solve-this-issue-or/)

Below is my XML file -

```
<CVs>
 <CV>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Address></Address>
  <Introduction></Introduction>
  <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, Oracle, VB.NET</CompSkills>
  <Experience>
    <Profile></Profile>
    <Duration></Duration>
    <Info></Info>
  </Experience>
  <Experience>
    <Profile></Profile>
    <Duration></Duration>
    <Info></Info>
  </Experience>
  <Experience>
    <Profile></Profile>
    <Duration></Duration>
    <Info></Info>
  </Experience>
<CV>
<CV>
 <Name>XYZ</Name>
 <Address></Address>
 <Introduction></Introduction>
 <CompSkills>Java, XSLT, XPATH, XML, JSP, HTML</CompSkills>
 <Experience>
   <Profile></Profile>
   <Duration></Duration>
   <Info></Info>
 </Experience>
 <Experience>
   <Profile></Profile>
   <Duration></Duration>
   <Info></Info>
 </Experience>
 <Experience>
   <Profile></Profile>
   <Duration></Duration>
   <Info></Info>
 </Experience>
```

Below is my XSLT file - (well Dimitre gave this answer, but now its mine ;) )

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pName" select="'XYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CV">
   <xsl:if test="$pName = Name or $pName='*'">
     <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT will extract matching `<Name>` which is passed from Java.

Now I need to know how can i modify this XSLT, so that if I pass **Oracle** as a parameter, then
those who have Oracle in `<CompSkills>` would get listed. Oracle will be one of the CompSkills..

Thanks in advance - John

Comment: Are you wanting get the `CV`s with "Oracle" in addition to `Name` or instead of `Name`?

Comment: @DevNull- :) answers for both would be an advantage. :) Thanks a lot - John

Comment: I've modified my answer so that it will match either skill or name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 1.0, easy way: [`contains`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function, e.g.:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(CompSkills, $pSkill)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `contains()`.

This modified version of your stylesheet will pull the `CV` if the `Name` matches the `pName` param or if `CompSkills` contains the `pSkill` param.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="pName" select="'XYZ'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pSkill" select="'Oracle'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CV">
    <xsl:if test="$pName = Name or $pName='*' or
                  contains(CompSkills,$pSkill)">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```